# imakeidx in the amsbook class makes incorrect header

Tags: header-footer, indexing, imakeidx, amsbook

When I use imakeidx package together with the amsbook document class I get an incorrect header "INDEX" instead of the designated title (in the example below "SUBJECT INDEX") on the last page of the index. Is there a way to fix this so that the header of each page in the index is the same "SUBJECT INDEX" ?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Subject Index,columns=1]

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
The issue occurs when the index has multiple pages. The last page of the index has a header INDEX which is incorrect/different from the header of all other index pages.
\index{a1} \index{a2} \index{a3} \index{a4} \index{a5} \index{a6} \index{a6} \index{a7}\index{a8} \index{a9} \index{a0}
\index{b1} \index{b2} \index{b3} \index{b4} \index{b5} \index{b6} \index{b6} \index{b7}\index{b8} \index{b9} \index{b0}
\index{c1} \index{c2} \index{c3} \index{c4} \index{c5} \index{c6} \index{c6} \index{c7}\index{c8} \index{c9} \index{c0}
\index{d1} \index{d2} \index{d3} \index{d4} \index{d5} \index{d6} \index{d6} \index{d7}\index{d8} \index{d9} \index{d0}
\index{e1} \index{e2} \index{e3} \index{e4} \index{e5} \index{e6} \index{e6} \index{e7}\index{e8} \index{e9} \index{e0}
\index{f1} \index{f2} \index{f3} \index{f4} \index{f5} \index{f6} \index{f6} \index{f7}\index{f8} \index{f9} \index{f0}
\index{g1} \index{g2} \index{g3} \index{g4} \index{g5} \index{g6} \index{g6} \index{g7}\index{g8} \index{g9} \index{g0}
\index{h1} \index{h2} \index{h3} \index{h4} \index{h5} \index{h6} \index{h6} \index{h7}\index{h8} \index{h9} \index{h0}
\index{k1} \index{k2} \index{k3} \index{k4} \index{k5} \index{k6} \index{k6} \index{k7}\index{k8} \index{k9} \index{k0}

\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean in the page headers of odd pages only, correct?

Comment: No, the problem is always with the last page of an index independently of whether it is even or odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a timing issue that seems to happen only with `amsbook` (that has a nonstandard management of headers).

Workaround in the code below.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[
  title=Subject Index,
  columns=1
]

\makeatletter
\def\imki@indexheaders{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\indexname}}{\MakeUppercase{\indexname}}%
  }\x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
The issue occurs when the index has multiple pages. The last page of the index has a header INDEX which is incorrect/different from the header of all other index pages.

\index{a1} \index{a2} \index{a3} \index{a4} \index{a5} \index{a6} \index{a6} \index{a7}\index{a8} \index{a9} \index{a0}

\index{b1} \index{b2} \index{b3} \index{b4} \index{b5} \index{b6} \index{b6} \index{b7}\index{b8} \index{b9} \index{b0}

\index{c1} \index{c2} \index{c3} \index{c4} \index{c5} \index{c6} \index{c6} \index{c7}\index{c8} \index{c9} \index{c0}

\index{d1} \index{d2} \index{d3} \index{d4} \index{d5} \index{d6} \index{d6} \index{d7}\index{d8} \index{d9} \index{d0}

\index{e1} \index{e2} \index{e3} \index{e4} \index{e5} \index{e6} \index{e6} \index{e7}\index{e8} \index{e9} \index{e0}

\index{f1} \index{f2} \index{f3} \index{f4} \index{f5} \index{f6} \index{f6} \index{f7}\index{f8} \index{f9} \index{f0}

\index{g1} \index{g2} \index{g3} \index{g4} \index{g5} \index{g6} \index{g6} \index{g7}\index{g8} \index{g9} \index{g0}

\index{h1} \index{h2} \index{h3} \index{h4} \index{h5} \index{h6} \index{h6} \index{h7}\index{h8} \index{h9} \index{h0}

\index{k1} \index{k2} \index{k3} \index{k4} \index{k5} \index{k6} \index{k6} \index{k7}\index{k8} \index{k9} \index{k0}

\index{l1} \index{l2} \index{l3} \index{l4} \index{l5} \index{l6} \index{l6} \index{l7}\index{l8} \index{l9} \index{l0}

\index{m1} \index{m2} \index{m3} \index{m4} \index{m5} \index{m6} \index{m6} \index{m7}\index{m8} \index{m9} \index{m0}

\index{n1} \index{n2} \index{n3} \index{n4} \index{n5} \index{n6} \index{n6} \index{n7}\index{n8} \index{n9} \index{n0}

\index{o1} \index{o2} \index{o3} \index{o4} \index{o5} \index{o6} \index{o6} \index{o7}\index{o8} \index{o9} \index{o0}

\backmatter
\printindex
\chapter{xxx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For an older TeX distribution (before TL 2022), the code should be

```
\makeatletter
\def\imki@indexheaders{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\@mkboth{\noexpand\MakeUppercase{\indexname}}{\noexpand\MakeUppercase{\indexname}}%
  }\x
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This example does not compile for me. I get the following error:
Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition.
\MakeUppercase  ...}\def \j {J}\def \reserved@a ##
                                                  1##2{\let ##1##2\reserved@...
l.1 \begin{theindex}
                    
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

Comment: @187334 You seem to be running an older TeX distribution. See the edit to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, the update for older LaTex fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: The following is only a workaround not a real solution!

A not very nice but working solution is, to rename `\indexname` before `\printindex`. If you have only one index, you can do this in the document preamble:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Subject Index,columns=1]
\renewcommand*{\indexname}{Subject Index}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
The issue occurs when the index has multiple pages. The last page of the index has a header INDEX which is incorrect/different from the header of all other index pages.
\index{a1} \index{a2} \index{a3} \index{a4} \index{a5} \index{a6} \index{a6} \index{a7}\index{a8} \index{a9} \index{a0}
\index{b1} \index{b2} \index{b3} \index{b4} \index{b5} \index{b6} \index{b6} \index{b7}\index{b8} \index{b9} \index{b0}
\index{c1} \index{c2} \index{c3} \index{c4} \index{c5} \index{c6} \index{c6} \index{c7}\index{c8} \index{c9} \index{c0}
\index{d1} \index{d2} \index{d3} \index{d4} \index{d5} \index{d6} \index{d6} \index{d7}\index{d8} \index{d9} \index{d0}
\index{e1} \index{e2} \index{e3} \index{e4} \index{e5} \index{e6} \index{e6} \index{e7}\index{e8} \index{e9} \index{e0}
\index{f1} \index{f2} \index{f3} \index{f4} \index{f5} \index{f6} \index{f6} \index{f7}\index{f8} \index{f9} \index{f0}
\index{g1} \index{g2} \index{g3} \index{g4} \index{g5} \index{g6} \index{g6} \index{g7}\index{g8} \index{g9} \index{g0}
\index{h1} \index{h2} \index{h3} \index{h4} \index{h5} \index{h6} \index{h6} \index{h7}\index{h8} \index{h9} \index{h0}
\index{k1} \index{k2} \index{k3} \index{k4} \index{k5} \index{k6} \index{k6} \index{k7}\index{k8} \index{k9} \index{k0}

\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: If you are using `babel` you have to do it, using `babel`'s user interface to change language dependent terms.

If you have more than one index, you would need to move the `\renewcommand` before each index (and change it corresponding to the individual index).

Comment: I'm sure Enrico knows a better solution, so I would recommend to also report the issue to the author.

Comment: it looks more like an amsbook problem, unlike e.g. book it doesn't expands commands in the title of headings when writing the marks, and so they can pick up later meanings.

Comment: I actually do have multiple indices and the issue shows up with each one of them. Your solution via renaming '\indexname' before '\printindex' works with a single index. For multiple indices the renaming for some reason shows up in the index preceding the renaming. So a workaround that works for multiple indices is to rename '\indexname' right **after** the corresponding '\printindex'.